# Laravel - connect to development server

Tags: apache, laravel, localhost, development-environment

I just installed laravel and need some clues regarding "development server" and how I can run a project.

I connected to laravel development center which opened port 8000 on localhost. So I access my project at

```
localhost:8000
```

It wouldn't work if I typed in localhost/thelaravelproject/somepage , as I do with other php projects during development.

After closing the command line tool, localhost:8000 became inactive, so I opened the command line again, entered the path, and then

```
php artisan serve
```

and then it was running again. Does this mean that I have to do this every time?

On this page [laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick) it says something about "Local Development Environment" and it mentions Laravel Homestead. Is this something that is needed to run laravel using localhost the way I normally work with php?

I follow tutorials, but it's strange how they leave out very important details.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that localhost works the normal way, I just have to add the '**public**' directory.

So if I type in

```
localhost/thelaravelproject/public
```

it shows the 'you have arrived' page.

Comment: that is because the index.php lies inside the public folder - Laravel has done that because of security reasons (that is a frequent measure - you can also check symfony and yii also keep index.php in public folder as well as static files - images, css, js).

Answer (score 0):

In laravel project Directory every things first goes to the public/index.php.
so it have to be in that directory.
you have to start from this
localhost/thelaravelproject/public.
following link will help you.